# Function is not called on click of div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using jQuery 1.7.2. Originally, my HTML was rendered on page load:

```
<div class="my_div_class">
  <button class="my_button_class" >
  </button>
<div>
```

Then I was registering below JavaScript function:

```
$(".my_div_class").on('click', function(event){ //function_1
}
```

It was working fine.

Because of some reason I need to change it to below

```
$(document).on('click','.my_div_class', function(event){}
```

Then its not working ? But If change above functiion to use `my_button_class` it works. Why it is not working with div ?

Comment: Not "for some reason" but for delegation reasons - change the button to type=button amd handle the event propagation - 1.7.2 WHY? And on was added in 1.7 anyway

Comment: Because you are clicking the button and not the div. Imagine the Div being behind the button. The div just acts as container for the button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",".my_div_class",function(event) {
        alert("Heyy! clicked me!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my_div_class">
  <button class="my_button_class" >
  </button>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(event.target).closest(".my_div_class").length == 1` to see if you clicked on `my_div_class` or any element inside it.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".my_div_class").length == 1) {
    console.log("clicked on button or div")
  } else {
    console.log("clicked outside")
  }
})
```

**demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".my_div_class").length == 1) {
    console.log("clicked on button or div")
  } else {
    console.log("clicked outside")
  }
})
```

```css
.my_div_class {
width:200px;
background-color:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_div_class">
  <button class="my_button_class">click
  </button>
  <div>
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But how come it works with `$(".my_div_class").on('click', function(event)` but not with `$(document).on('click','.my_div_class', function(event)` when i am clicking on same place in both cases ?

Comment: @scottmiles because your not clicking on `my_div_class` but the button